# Upgrading font awesome icons in gatsby react project, new icons not working

Tags: css, reactjs, font-awesome, gatsby

I'm working on a react project using a gatsby html5up template.  I'm upgrading font awesome icons from 4.7 to 5.12.  The 4.7 icons were working, so I'm basing my new file locations off the old ones.

I downloaded the all.css file and the webfonts folder.  Rather than delete everything just yet, I've added them into new and existing folders.

In my main.scss:

```
//@import '../css/font-awesome.min.css';
@import '../css/all.css';
```

Then in my src/assets/css folder, I added my all.css file, the same location that the 4.7 font-awesome.min.css is located.

Then I downloaded and added the webfonts folder to src/assets.

My project builds with no errors, but the icons are not showing.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out and posting here in case someone else has the same issue.
The dependencies for this project:

```
    "gatsby": "^2.15.14",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.2.16",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.0.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.7",
    "gatsby-plugin-sass": "^2.1.14",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1"
```

The template I'm using is `gatsby-starter-forty-v2`

Steps to take:

From fontawesome website, Download the `all.css` file and place in `/src/assets/css` folder.
Download the `webfonts` folder and place in `/src/assets` folder
(`all.css` references the `webfonts` folder by name, must keep name and structure)

In `/src/assets/scss/main.scss`
Replace the old import:
`//@import '../css/font-awesome.min.css';`
`@import '../css/all.css';`

In `/src/assets/scss/libs/_mixins.scss`
Comment out font-family for `@mixin icon`:
`//font-family: FontAwesome;`

In `/src/assets/css/all.css`
Edit font-weight from `400` to `900` for `.far` and `@font-face`:
 `font-weight: 900; }`

Finally, clean up previous 4.7 version, although it worked without doing this:

Delete `/src/assets/fonts` folder

Delete `/src/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css`

For the brand icons I had to add class `fab` to the displayed icon `<a href="#" className="icon alt fab fa-linkedin">`
For the free icons I had to add class `fas` to the displayed icon `<span className="icon alt fas fa-phone"></span>`